# Excel VBA - Copy all csv from one folder into existing workbook as separate worksheets

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I am looking to create a macro that takes all .csv files from one folder and copies them into a pre-existing workbook, where all of the sheets have the same name as the source .csv file.

I have found the code below (unfortunately, I do not remember where I exactly found it and cannot cite the author) Right now it only does part of what I'm looking for. It allows the user to select the folder where the .csv files are at, but it creates a new workbook and copies the files into that. I would like for the macro to also prompt the user to select the destination workbook for the files to be copied into.

```
Option Explicit

Sub csvCopier()

Dim wkb As Workbook
Dim wksDest As Worksheet
Dim strData As String
Dim x As Variant
Dim Cnt As Long
Dim r As Long
Dim c As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

'Optimize Macro Speed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
  Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

With FldrPicker
  .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
  .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
  myPath = myPath
  If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
  myExtension = "*.csv*"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
  myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

If Right(myPath, 1) <> "\" Then myPath = myPath & "\"

myFile = Dir(myPath & "*.csv")

Do While Len(myFile) > 0

    Cnt = Cnt + 1

    If Cnt = 1 Then
        Set wkb = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
    End If

    Open myPath & myFile For Input As #1

        Set wksDest = wkb.Worksheets.Add

        wksDest.Name = Left(myFile, InStr(1, myFile, ".csv") - 1)

        r = 2
        c = 1
        Do Until EOF(1)
            Line Input #1, strData
            x = Split(strData, ",")
            For i = LBound(x) To UBound(x)
                Cells(r, c).Value = x(i)
                c = c + 1
            Next i
            r = r + 1
            c = 1
        Loop

    Close #1

    myFile = Dir

Loop

   If Cnt > 0 Then
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wkb.Worksheets(wkb.Worksheets.Count).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Completed...", vbInformation
    Else
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "No CSV files found...", vbExclamation
    End If

ResetSettings:
'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: it creates a new workbook and it does not save it?

Comment: @jsotola it creates a new workbook, but does not save it automatically. I'm looking to have the code prompt the user to open an existing workbook first and that workbook will be used as the destination for the copies

Comment: so, just do web search for `open workbook using vba`  ... there should be a lot of examples

Answer (score 1):

The code below does what you describe; that is it "takes all .csv files from one folder and copies them into a pre-existing workbook, where all of the sheets have the same name as the source .csv file".

To produce the code, I first imported one of the `.csv` files using the macro recorder, and then modified the code to handle the general case of multiple files in the same folder. I also removed a lot of unnecessary code. You should be able to modify this code to suit your needs.

```
Option Explicit
Sub csvToSheets()
Dim wk As Workbook, sh As Worksheet, s As String
Const path = "C:\test\"
  s = Dir(path & "*.csv")
While s <> ""
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    Set sh = ActiveSheet


    With sh.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & path & s, _
        Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = s
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    sh.Name = Left(s, Len(s) - 4)
    s = Dir()
Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tony. I tried your code, but whenever I have more than 1 workbook open (say, PERSONAL.XLSB and the destination workbook), the macro creates blank sheets in one book and copies all of the data onto a single sheet in the other book

Comment: I've made a small change, using the sh variable instead of ActiveSheet (since when debugging ActiveSheet can cause problems). Keep in mind that my code is just intended to get you started. I hope that helps

Comment: Yes it helped! Thank you

Comment: Glad you've been helped. If you think your question has been answered please mark it as answered